# What is the purpose of providedIn with the Injectable decorator when generating Services in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

When generating services in the Angular CLI, it is adding extra metadata with a 'provided in' property with a default of 'root' for the Injectable decorator.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

What exactly does providedIn do?  I am assuming this is making the service available like a 'global' type singleton service for the whole application, however, wouldn't be cleaner to declare such services in the provider array of the AppModule?

Comment: I think your updates should be an answer (you can answer your own questions) instead of adding it to your question.

Comment: The most important part is SINGLETON, no one mentions it!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

if you use providedIn, the injectable is registered as a provider of the Module without adding it to the providers of the module.

From [`Docs`](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules)

> The service itself is a class that the CLI generated and that's
>   decorated with @Injectable. By default, this decorator is configured
>   with a providedIn property, which creates a provider for the service.
>   In this case, providedIn: 'root' specifies that the service should be
>   provided in the root injector.

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan.  Okay, so it sounds like it's a new shortcut way of specifying where the service should be provided.  I guess my initial preference would have been looking at a module's provider list to see all the services that are declared as providers, rather than perusing the scattered code base for ProvidedIn tags .... (?)

Comment: Was there any reason for Angular to add this? Is there a problem this is solving? I don't see there being a reason for this.

Comment: Keeps the AppModule / CoreModule definition a little smaller ;)

Comment: @prolink007. Using providedIn allows the services to be lazy-loaded by the app. To test this, put console logs in your services. My home page used to load 16 services, now it loads 9. It's hard to quantify the performance, but I feel better knowing that I'm not loading services until they're needed :).

Comment: @prolink007 From [the doc](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services):

"Registering the provider in the @Injectable() metadata also allows Angular to optimize an app by removing the service from the compiled app if it isn't used."

Comment: You can make your services tree-shakeable by using the `providedIn` attribute to define where the service should be initialized when using the `@Injectable()` decorator. Then you should remove it from the providers attribute of your `NgModule` declaration as well as its import statement.This can help reduce the bundle size by removing unused code from the bundle.

Answer (score 167):

`providedIn: 'root'` is the easiest and most efficient way to provide services since Angular 6:

1. The service will be available application wide as a singleton with no need to add it to a module's providers array (like Angular <= 5).
2. If the service is only used within a lazy loaded module it will be lazy loaded with that module
3. If it is never used it will not be contained in the build (tree shaked).

For further informations consider reading the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service) and [NgModule FAQs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq)

Btw:

1. If you don't want a application-wide singleton use the provider's array of a component instead.
2. If you want to limit the scope so no other developer will ever use your service outside of a particular module, use the `providers` array of NgModule instead.

Comment: Question! My service will very certainly rely on other services (via DI in its constructor). Before, all the dependencies would be managed in the module providing the service... What about now?
Especially if it relies on a third-party library (not using providedIn: root), how on earth do we manage?

Answer (score 121):

*From Docs*

> What is Injectable decorator?

Marks a class as available to Injector for creation.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

The service itself is a class that the CLI generated and that's decorated with @Injectable().

> What exactly does providedIn do?

Determines which injectors will provide the injectable, by either associating it with an @NgModule or other InjectorType, or by specifying that this injectable should be provided in the 'root' injector, which will be the application-level injector in most apps.

```
providedIn: Type<any> | 'root' | null
```

> providedIn: 'root'

When you provide the service at the root level, Angular creates a single, shared instance of service and injects it into any class that asks for it. Registering the provider in the @Injectable() metadata also allows Angular to optimize an app by removing the service from the compiled app if it isn't used.

> providedIn: Module

It's also possible to specify that a service should be provided in a particular @NgModule. For example, if you don't want a service to be available to applications unless they import a module you've created, you can specify that the service should be provided in the module

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModule } from './user.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: UserModule,
})
export class UserService {
}
```

This method is preferred because it enables Tree-shaking (***Tree shaking*** is a step in a build process that removes unused code from a code base) of the service if nothing injects it.

If it's not possible to specify in the service which module should provide it, you can also declare a provider for the service within the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {
}
```

Comment: What about when it's empty, such as ```@Injectable()```?

Comment: if we use providers in NgModule then what whould be the value of provideIn at service ?

Comment: When its @Injectable() without additional 'providedIn' meta, then it must be declared in providers array at module level. Then it will not be available to other modules and becomes unique to that module branch.

Comment: In the last 2 examples, why is there no cyclic dependency? Since `UserModule` is using `UserService` in `providers` and `UserService` is using `UserModule` in `providedIn`?

Comment: @itsji10dra you do either one of the other, they have the same result.

Comment: What about the last proposed approach for standalone components? 
`providedIn: null` into the injectable class + `providers: MyLocalInjectable` into the standalone component?

Answer (score 63):

This is a fresh reply that's up to date with Angular 9+ (post-Ivy) and should be correct in 2022.

---

**TL;DR**: It's all about controlling how many instances of your service will be created, and where should they be available after being created.

---

**Terminology:**

- **Injectable** - any class decorated with `@Injectable`, for example a service.
- **injector** - an Angular class that is capable of providing Injectables to classes below it. (This includes all components and modules.)
- **injector scope/level** - the scope of all class instances that live "below" a specific injector.
- **injector hierarchy** - a proritized tree of injector scopes, organized in `platform -> root -> module -> component` order.
- Injectable is **provided** - an instance of the Injectable will be given to classes below this specific injector level, whenever they request it.
- Injectable is **injected** - a class constructor has requested to be given some instance of the service, so Angular will try to [give it the nearest instance that can be found in the injector hierarchy](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-rules)".
- **tree-shaking** - an optimization that happens automatically thanks to the Angular compiler. When it detects that some code is not being used, that code is removed from the final compilation of the app (or compilation of a given lazy-loaded module).

Other terms that you should already know: **class, instance, module, component, lazy/eagerly loaded modules**.

---

**Q: What exactly does `providedIn` do?**

It's a setting that determines which injectors should provide your Injectable.

Let's assume we create an Injectable called `MyService`, and go through what [all the options](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#options) do.

```
providedIn: Type<any> | 'root' | 'platform' | 'any' | null
```

> `providedIn: 'platform'`

Angular will create and provide a single shared instance of `MyService` to all Angular *applications* on the page. (This is only relevant in advanced use cases, if you use a micro-frontends architecture.)

> `providedIn: 'root'`

Angular will create a single shared instance of `MyService` and provide it to all classes in the application.

> `providedIn: 'any'` // DEPRECATED since Angular v15

Angular will create a single shared instance of `MyService` and provide it to all classes *in eagerly-loaded modules*.

However, each *lazy-loaded module* will provide its own, new, separate instance of `MyService` (that will then be only available in classes inside that module).

> `providedIn: MyModule` // DEPRECATED since Angular v15

Angular will only create an instance of `MyService` if `MyModule` is loaded.

If `MyModule` is *eagerly loaded*, that instance will be available to all other eagerly loaded modules from now on. (Note that this is effectively identical to `providedIn: 'root'`.)

However, if `MyModule` is *lazy loaded*, then this instance will be provided only for classes inside `MyModule`, whenever it happens to be loaded.

> `providedIn: MyComponent` // DEPRECATED since Angular v15

Angular will create a new, fresh instance of `MyService` whenever `MyComponent` is instantiated.

This `MyService` instance will only be provided for descendants of that specific `MyComponent` *instance*, and will be destroyed as soon as the component instance is destroyed. (Note that means that a new `MyService` will be created for each time this component is rendered.)

> `providedIn: null`

`MyService` can only ever be instantiated by being added to `providers` array in a specific module or component.

Whenever that module/component is instantiated, it will create a new instance of `MyService`, and provide it only in its specific scope. (See full description of `providers` array below.)

---

**Q: What does `providers` array do?**

Any injector can be set up with a `providers` array:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [MyService],
})

@Component({
  providers: [MyService],
})
```

All Injectables can be added to a `providers` array, *regardless* of their `providedIn` setting.

Adding `MyService` to `providers` array will cause the injector to create and provide an entirely separate instance of it to classes in its scope. (The scope is exactly the same as described in `providedIn: MyModule` and `providedIn: MyComponent` examples above.)

This method of providing does not support tree-shaking. The service will always be included in the compilation, even if noone uses it. (See tree-shaking notes below.)

**Q: Why would I use `providers` array *and* `providedIn` simultaneously?**

An example use case might be if `MyService` is `providedIn: 'root'` and already has a shared instance, but you want your module/component to have its own, separate instance.

---

**Additional notes:**

**Q: How do `providedIn`/`providers` settings affect tree-shaking?**

An Injectable *configured with `providedIn`* will be tree-shaken if it is not injected by any (eagerly or lazy loaded) class in its assigned injector scope.

However, an *Injectable assigned to a `providers` array* in some module/component will never be tree-shaken, even if it is not injected anywhere.

To make tree-shaking most effective, you should aim to always use `providedIn` over `providers` array.

**Q: Why would I use `providedIn: 'root'` if I think using `providers` array in `AppModule` looks cleaner?**

As explained above, the main difference is that between the two methods, `providedIn` supports tree-shaking, and `providers` array does not.

Other than that, it's an architectural decision: if we set `providedIn` directly in the Injectable file, the Injectable *owns* the decision of how it should be provided. Distinguishing *who owns the contract* has significant implications for large apps and teams that have to cooperate between hundreds of modules.

**Q: Is there a difference between setting `providers: [MyService]` array in `AppComponent` or `AppModule`?**

Yes. `MyService` will be provided in lazy-loaded modules *only* if you do it in `AppModule`, not `AppComponent`.

(That's because lazy-loaded modules rely on `Router`, which gets imported in `AppModule`, one injector scope higher than `AppComponent`.)

Comment: very clear and up to date answer, thx!

Comment: Thank you for this thorough and up to date answer! Shoutout to the definitions section, very helpful when you're still learning Angular!

Answer (score 41):

see Excellent explanation by [@Nipuna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741555/10211220),

I'd like to extend it by adding examples.

if you just use Injectable decorator without `providedin` property, like,

```
@Injectable()
```

then you would have to write service's name in respective Module's `providers` Array.

like this;

data.service.ts ↴

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor() {}

    // Code . . .
}
```

app.module.ts ↴

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DataService } from './core/data.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [DataService],    // ⟵ LOOK HERE WE PROVIDED IT
    imports: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But, If you use `providedIn: 'root'`, like this:

data.service.ts ↴

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
    constructor() {}

    // Code . . .
}
```

Then our module would look like this:

app.module.ts ↴

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DataService } from './core/data.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    imports: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

see I didn't add `DataService` in `providers` array this time, because it's not needed.

### Good Practices

This might come in handy, from [Angular Guides](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#providing-a-service)

> **Do provide a service with the app root injector in the @Injectable decorator of the service.**
>
> **Why?** The Angular injector is hierarchical.
>
> **Why?** When you provide the service to a root injector, that instance of the service is shared and available in every class that needs the service. This is ideal when a service is sharing methods or state.
>
> **Why?** When you register a service in the @Injectable decorator of the service, optimization tools such as those used by the Angular CLI's production builds can perform tree shaking and remove services that aren't used by your app.
>
> **Why?** This is not ideal when two different components need different instances of a service. In this scenario it would be better to provide the service at the component level that needs the new and separate instance.

Answer (score 18):

providedIn tells Angular that the root injector is responsible for creating an instance of the your Service. Services that are provided this way are automatically made available to the entire application and don't need to be listed in any module.

Service classes can act as their own providers which is why defining them in the @Injectable decorator is all the registration you need.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [`Documentation`](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services):

> Registering the provider in the @Injectable() metadata also allows
>   Angular to optimize an app by removing the service from the compiled
>   app if it isn't used.

Answer (score 2):

Simply..

`providedIn :'root'` creates one instance to the whole application without the need to provide it from any `NgModule`. Just declaring it in the service through the `@Injectable` decorator.

if you want to have one new instance of this service for any component, then declare it through component's provider. this will create another new instance for this component and its child components if any. thus, you can have one instance with global scope and another instance for one component.

Comment: So if we declare a `providedIn:root` service in the providers array of the component, then will the service be scoped to the component and child components only (Even though is has the `providedIn:root` metadata configuration) ?

Comment: @Ole `providedIn:root` is only declared in the service `@Injectable` doing so makes the service a singleton service (one instance for all components). if you need to instantiate a new instance of that service to a certain component, you can r egister that service to the component's provider's array and you can esnure it will take new instance by using  @self() when injecting it in the component's constructor. doing so will create a new instance to this component and its child components