# <Closed> Angular 6 ERROR TypeError: this.service.... is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm running a function that's calling a method in a service class. However I'm getting this error:
`ERROR TypeError: this.service.execute is not a function`.

I read [Angular 6: ERROR TypeError: "... is not a function" - but it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763745/angular-6-error-typeerror-is-not-a-function-but-it-is) but I don't see any problems with the type I specified, and I'm wondering if something else might be wrong.

Here are extracts of my code:
**exec.component.ts**

```
export class ExecComponent {
   name: string = "";
   age: string;
   date: string; 

constructor(protected service: ExecutorService){}

executeTask(): void {
   this.service.execute(this.name, this.date, this.age).subscribe((result: Result) => {
   if (result.isSuccess())
      console.log("Success!");
   else {
      console.log("Error");
   }
});

}
```

**exec.service.ts**

```
export class ExecutorService {
   execute(name: string, date: string, age: string): Observable<Result>{
      return new Observable<Result>();
   }
}
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: still not clear can you share the exec service the whole file ?

Comment: hello @malbarmawi I can but the other parts of the service file aren't relevant to the execute method at all, so I don't think showing it would add much value :/

Comment: check this everything is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqddr6

Comment: ExecutorService is not your service thats y change it to private

Comment: try changing protected to private

`constructor(private service: ExecutorService){}`

Comment: @ORBIT I still get the same error when I change it to private. Although the reasoning is interesting, do we use protected for service written by ourselves? why?

Comment: @IceTea according to Angular  the use Add a private heroService parameter of type HeroService to the constructor.https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: if you put  `console.log("execute:", this.service.execute);` before the actual call, what is logged?. How is  executeTask() called? and Please post the entire code of the ExecutorService. There is obviously something wrong with the service because as you can see from @malbarmawi example, it works if you do it properly

Comment: the code I've written above can compile, but there's an error when it is called. I can't see the console log in stackblitz, so I'm not sure if @malbarmawi is actually working

Comment: it is working, there is a console bar in the bottom right on stackblitz that you can open. And just because it compiles doesnt mean its correct. for example if you misplaces a `}` and the execute function is outside the `ExecutorService` class. That would compile, but the function would not be part of the service. Even better would be if you could create an example on stackblitz that shows your error

Comment: @x4rf41 thanks for pointing the console out! I'll try to create a stackblitz to replicate this error

Comment: The name of the class that you're exporting in the service is different from the one that you're using in the component to declare the service variable.

Comment: have you added the service into a module in the `providers` array or done the following as indicated here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848357/what-is-the-purpose-of-providedin-with-the-injectable-decorator-when-generating Where is the decorator for the service?

Comment: hi all, thanks so much for your assistance. Unfortunately I am unable to replicate the problem when I extract out the code, so I'm going to go step by step and add the other code I have slowly to find the problem. It'll take a long while because there are too many interactions between different libraries/services/classes so I'm closing this thread for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure why myself, but after many trials, I realised that this missing line in my service code `static ngInjectableDef = undefined;` is causing the error. I am unable to post the service code due to proprietary reason but hopefully this resolves someone's issue.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the position of the function I'was calling before handle error function to the top and injected the service through constructor rather than using Inject(). And it worked for me.

I'll post again if i find the proper reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this I think there is some typo in your code

```
  executeTask(): void {
    this.service.execute(this.name, this.date, this.age).subscribe((result: Result) => {
    if (result.isSuccess()){
       console.log("Success!");
    }
    else {
       console.log("Error");
  });
```

Comment: Hi Tony, I do have some typos, apologies as I was only extracting certain parts of my code! I have modified it. Unfortunately, the typos aren't the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

this turn out to be binding issue, i was passing the function to an event emitter and the "this" was bind to the sub component.

just changed my function as arrow function fixed everything.

**before:**

```
    this.someService.getReplyFile(file)
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(a => { });
  }
```

**after:**

```
  downloadReplyFile = (file: UploadedDocument) => {
    this.someService.getReplyFile(file)
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this)))
      .subscribe(a => { });
  }
```