# What is the difference between providedIn any and root

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-dependency-injection

In Angular 9 the injectable decorator option `providedIn` has a new value called `any`. What is the difference between `root` and `any`?

Is a service considered a singleton in the case that I use `any`?

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'any'})
class UsefulService {
}
```

Comment: `any` is a super confusing name (I'm sure there was about a month long discussion on the name though!) It's easier if you read `providedIn` in your head as `provided by which ngModule`

Comment: very detailed answer > https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561645/5578092

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think provided answers are not really clear. However, @jkonst, @schrödingcöder and @Bruce are correct in the comment.

For any one sent here by Google,

**any** doesn't Provides a unique instance in every module. (should say only in every shared module)

Which means one instance in every **inject scope**

from https://angular.io/guide/providers

> With providedIn: 'any', all eagerly loaded modules share a singleton instance; however, lazy loaded modules each get their own unique instance, as shown in the following diagram.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Thanks @malbarmavi , kudos to everyone who patriciates this thread. I had the same question like you as well.

Answer (score 29):

The difference between the `root` and `any` as per [offical documentation](https://next.angular.io/api/core/Injectable) :

- `root` : The application-level injector in most apps.
- `platform` : A special singleton platform injector shared by all
  applications on the page.
- `any` : The NgModule injector that receives the resolution.

For more details please refer this [article](https://dev.to/christiankohler/improved-dependeny-injection-with-the-new-providedin-scopes-any-and-platform-30bb).

Is a service considered a singleton in the case that I use `any`? - **No**

Comment: is it correct to say in every module I use the service that has `any` option I will have a new instance of that service 

Comment: yes it is correct. Please mark this as answer if it was helpful.

Comment: the article has fully information about the new options `any` and `platform` , thanks 

Comment: Seems that the quoted article states for "any" that  "All eagerly loaded modules share one instance provided by the root module injector." Presumably this means that only a lazy module will have its new instance.

Comment: It is not correct to say that in every module you have a new instance of that service. Eagerly loaded modules share one instance. This is explaned also in angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 10):

angular 9 introduce new option for injectable decorator ProvidedIn in addition to the previous `root` and module options, now we have two additional options
 `platform` , `any`

> **root**— This tells Angular to provide the service in the application root level and the service will be *created once* ([singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service)
>   ) and provide the **same  instance** in every module that injects the token.
>
> **any**— Provides a **unique instance** in every module (including lazy
>   modules) that injects the token.
>
> **platform**— Specifying providedIn: 'platform' makes the service
>   available in a special singleton platform injector that is shared by
>   all applications on the page.

[a detailed look at Angular's 'root' and 'any' provider scopes](https://indepth.dev/angulars-root-and-any-provider-scopes/)

Comment: According to Angular documentation,  "any" will provides a unique instance in lazy modules only but  all eagerly loaded modules will share a singleton instance. So how can it be that "any" provides a unique instance in EVERY module?

Comment: @Bruce, you are correct. It's an instance per module injector scope. Basically one instance per runtime bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Eg: Angular app

Module1 - Comp1 | Module2 - Comp2 | Module3 - Comp3 | Module4 - Comp4

Service - used in all the components

**providedIn:'root'**

-> single instance of service throughout the application
independent of modules/component/lazyloading etc.

**providedIn: 'any'**

-> Eager Loading => single instance (works same as provideIn:'root')

-> Lazy Loading => each lazyloading module will have a separate instance of the service