# providedIn platform vs root

Tags: angular, angular9

I am struggling to see which one of the `root` and the `platform` options for `providedIn` in a service is better.

Both make a service available in the whole application, the latter through a service and the former through the root injector. Any advice on this?

Comment: Upvoted because I'm also interested in knowing the answer; I would assume it has to do with the improved lazyloading capabalities that come with angular 9.

Comment: Seems like we already have discussed this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892369/what-is-the-difference-between-providedin-any-and-root

Comment: Does it mean that if I run a single app, both are equivalent ?

Comment: Have you read https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable? Unless you have multiple applications in a page, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I certainly did, and while "yes it doesn't matter" maybe it would matter performance wise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between providedIn any and root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892369/what-is-the-difference-between-providedin-any-and-root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the `root` and `any` as per [offical documentation](https://next.angular.io/api/core/Injectable) :

- `root` : The application-level injector in most apps.
- `platform` : A special singleton platform injector shared by all
  applications on the page.
- `any` : The NgModule injector that receives the resolution.

For more details please refer this [article](https://dev.to/christiankohler/improved-dependeny-injection-with-the-new-providedin-scopes-any-and-platform-30bb).

Is a service considered a singleton in the case that I use `any`? - **No**

To go back to the original question between `root` & `platform`, when using a single application in your project, it doesn't change anything performance wise.